# How to filter only posts that are community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki, search

How to filter only posts that are community wiki? I got aware of the existence of the community wiki today, but I don't know how to filter only CW posts. I'm in need of some help because I'm searching for some time and I still didn't find it.

Comment: You can find more tips for advanced search [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/search).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the search box write `wiki:1` for CW posts and `wiki:0` for non-CW posts.

Of course this can be in addition to other search parameters (tag, user, etc.)